# Flat file (.csv) import into SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, csv

I have problem with special signs while importing `.csv` file into my SQL Server database.

Special letters from the Slavic alphabet are converted into random signs. I am importing using wizard tool, tried also ANSI-1250 code, but it did not help.

Comment: You need to make sure you're using unicode data types. On the "Advanced" tab of the import export wizard for a flat file source, make sure the fields that contain unicode data are set to `[DT_WSTR]` not `[DT_STR]`

Comment: What is source file encoding? UTF-8 needs codepage 65001.

Comment: @Xedni your soulution helped. Problem solved, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just posting this as an answer in case anyone has a similar issue.

You can set up the datatypes of the fields you parse from flat files using the Import/Export wizard.

On the "Advanced" tab for a flat file source, make sure the fields that contain unicode data are set to `[DT_WSTR]` and not `[DT_STR]`. The former handles unicode characters correctly.

[image: Configuring Unicode for Import/Export]